# Is there anyway to review my voice after recording it in Skype?

Tags: skype

In Skype after recording a voice message I don't find any option to hear it, I wonder if I am missing something or this in fact doesn't exist ?

Answer (score 0):

[From Skype FAQ:](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10473/setting-up-voice-messaging-windows-desktop)

```
Make sure Receive unanswered calls as a voice message is checked. This means Voice Messaging is turned on and the default voicemail greeting is set.

To record your own voicemail greeting, click the Record button and speak into your computer’s microphone.

When you’ve finished recording your message, click the Stop button.

To listen to your greeting, click the Playback button.
```

Comment: Noticed: http://superuser.com/questions/531566/can-i-review-my-voice-message-after-recording-it

Comment: @JatSing: In future you may want to edit your existing question and flag for it to be reopened by a mod.

Comment: I will delete the old post tomorrow.

Comment: @Ofiris,strange. I didn't see the Playback button.

Comment: @JatSing, now you see it ?

Comment: @Ofiris, still not. I only see the play button beside my contact's voice message but mine. Could you show a pic about it ?